# Django Suspicious File Operation joined path is located outside of the base path

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

When running python manage.py collectstatic i get the following exception:

> django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path
>   (/Users/global_assets/images/backgrounds/seamless.png) is located
>   outside of the base path component .....

Although I can't find where this file is located in my project and where it is requested.

This is my settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<AWESOME SECRET KEY>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'messaging.apps.MessagingConfig',
    'businesses.apps.BusinessesConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'storages',
    'django_countries',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'beldashboard.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'dashboard.context_processors.client_list',
                'dashboard.context_processors.usertype',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'beldashboard.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dashboard/static'),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard-home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'




django_heroku.settings(locals())

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-3' #change to your region
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
APPEND_SLASH=False
```

I have also installed django_heroku

Comment: Please post your settings file.

Comment: Done! @2ps settings.py

Comment: There must be something referring to `global_assets/images/backgrounds/seamless.png` in a way that causes Django to resolve it to `/Users/global_assets/images/backgrounds/seamless.png`. Try doing a search in all files in your project, it's most likely some `css` file and the reference might be something like `'../../../../global_assets/images/backgrounds/seamless.png'`.

Comment: @jaap3 I also thought so but could find it with the Finder. I now made deeper research on my files and I found the references. So thank you for the tip !!